# The max Length is not showing until value is inputted and also after Backspacing it is decreasing to 31 characters

Tags: javascript, html, function, onkeydown, onkeypress

The value of Max length is to be 30 when loaded, and again 30 after backspacing all characters.

```
<input onkeypress="chars(),maxLen()" onkeydown="back()" maxlength="30" type="text" placeholder="Title....." id="inpuT1" class="input">
<br>
Max Length <span id="chars"></span>
```

Also I have to give two inputs or two backspaces halfway to change the value. I need it to just be like the Stackoverflow question box where it says 'x' characters left.

```
//Maximum input length
document.getElementById("chars").innerHTML=result;
function chars(){
var inputValue = document.getElementById("inpuT1").value;
var textnode = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
var maxlen = 30;
var result;
result=maxlen-textnode.length;
document.getElementById("chars").innerHTML=result;
}

//Key down
function back(){
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inpuT1").value;
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  var maxlen=30;
  var result;
    result=maxlen-textnode.length;
    document.getElementById("chars").innerHTML=result+1;
}

//Maximum input length
function maxLen(){ 
var inputValue = document.getElementById("inpuT1").value;
var textnode = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  if(textnode.length>29){
   alert("Max Length reached !!!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the same name `chars` for the function and the element ID. Both of these become global variables, and it's not clear which one takes precedence.

Comment: Check the console, there may be an error saying that `chars` is not a function.

Comment: `textnode.length` should be `inputValue.length`

Answer (score -1):

```js
inpuT1.addEventListener(
  'keyup', 
   ({ target: { value: { length } } }) => {
     console.log(length)
     chars.innerText = 30 - length
   }
)
```

```html
<input maxlength="30" type="text" placeholder="Title....." id="inpuT1" class="input">
<br>
Characters left: <span id="chars"></span>
```